# Application of Jensens inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is it possible to use Jensen's inequality to show 
$$C\big(\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}\big)^q \geq \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}^q$$
for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q \in [0,1]$?

I managed to show the other direction quite easily but i'm really struggling with this one. The function is convex down so Jensen's inequality applies, I have a feeling that this is the right way to go but I've had no luck so far.

**Edit**
Sorry I just noticed I left out the definitions of all these terms; $k \in \mathbb{N}$; the $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $a_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ and the $C$ may depend on $k$ and $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto x^q$ for $q \in [0,1]$ is concave, and so $\mathbb{E}[X^q] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]^q$. In particular,
$$ \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k a_i^q \leq \left(\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k a_i\right)^q. $$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^q \leq k^{1-q} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\right)^q.
$$